# Hook up Auth0AccountController in Umbraco 7

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-routing, umbraco, umbraco7, auth0

Has anyone successfully integrated [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) with Umbraco 7 for member (front-end public users, not CMS back-end users) authentication?

I've successfully integrated with owin startup and dealing with signin-auth0 response. However I'm stuck on hooking up the Auth0AccountController to work with Umbraco (I'm getting a 404). Any suggestions?

I've tried adding ~/Auth0Account to the "umbracoReservedPaths" appSetting, but I just get a slightly different looking 404 (not controlled by Umbraco by looks of it).

I've also tried mapping the route in Startup.cs using

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    "Auth0Account",
    "Auth0Account/{action}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Auth0Account"
    }
);
```

but that results in a "No route in the route table matches the supplied values" error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping the Auth0Account route in Startup.cs was correct:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    "Auth0Account",
    "Auth0Account/{action}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Auth0Account"
    }
);
```

Turns out my problem was with the default redirect `RedirectToLocal` method in the `Auth0AccountController` controller. It was doing a

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

which I didn't have a controller hooked up for. I replaced this with an Umbraco compatible redirect instead.

Also, instead of `Auth0AccountController` inheriting from `Controller` it might be useful to inherit from `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController` or `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController` to expose useful Umbraco methods to the code.